# How to buy the same item twice using Android in-app billings?

Tags: java, android

I use standard Android example of in-app billing, and there is the following code for paying:

```
 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(GiftsActivity.this, "10starts", 1, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
```

This code allows user to buy 10 stars and improves his rating. But in this case he can't do it again; I don't want to restrict him then I need to give him an ability to buy stars again and again. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to consume the item first.. in API Level 3, you can only buy the item once. This is done for the consumer's protection and to safeguard the developer as well.

Call consumeAsync(Purchase, OnConsumeFinishedListener) on your IabHelper instance.

Then you'll be able to launchPurchaseFlow and purchase the same item again

Comment: Hmm... thanks. But now how can I cancel my last transaction? Because when I executes my app again I can't consume my latest purchase

Comment: you'll need to queryInventoryAsync(); first, get the purchaseId, construct the Purchase object and consumeAsync();